# Prolog: Finding all 3x3 magic squares without using clp(FD)

Tags: prolog, magic-square

I want to find all possible 3x3 magic squares.

Quoting from [English wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square):

> A magic square is an arrangement of distinct numbers (i.e. each number is used once), usually integers, in a square grid, where the numbers in each row, and in each column, and the numbers in the main and secondary diagonals, all add up to the same number.

Here's *one* sample solution:

> 8 1 6
>   3 5 7
>   4 9 2

How can I write a Prolog program that finds *all* solutions without using `library(clpfd)`?

Comment: Can you use SWI-Prolog and library clfpd ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with SWI-Prolog but not clpfd:

```
square(L) :-
    setof(S, carre(S), L).

carre(L) :-
    L = [[A, B, C],
         [D, E, F],
         [G, H, I]],
    flatten(L, LF),
    numlist(1,9, LN),
    init(LF, LN),
    15 is A + B + C,
    15 is D + E + F,
    15 is G + H + I,
    15 is A + D + G,
    15 is B + E + H,
    15 is C + F + I.

init([H|T], L) :-
    select(H, L, L1),
    init(T, L1).
init([], []).
```

Comment: I describe what you want in carre(L), and I ask Prolog to give me all the solutions in square(L). Now, what is L (in carre) : it is composed of 9 variables chosen between 1 and 9 (predicate init) and I say that all the sums are 15. Prolog solves the problem using backtrack.